# Significance of Contents.xml file in eclipse plugin jar

Tags: eclipse-plugin

Can anyone explain me the importance of contents.xml file for eclipse plug-in development?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `contexts.xml` file.

This contains context sensitive help used in the UI.

http://help.eclipse.org/luna/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/ua_help_context_xml.htm?cp=46_0_19_1_2_1

Answer (score 1):

'content.xml' (no s) is part of the p2 installer update site (also know as a repository). More details [here](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.pde.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fupdate_site.htm)